# Order by nil value in column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-order-by

I have table with column `position`, which in some cases, for some collection of records can be `nil`. I have default order options like
`order('positions ASC')`

```
id| name | position
1    5       null
2    6       null
3    7       null
```

If for some collection that I sort (example above), all values have `null` in position `column`, in which order I will get this collection from db?
I'm suggestion I will get collection in order of ids (`1,2,3`). Am I correct?

Addition #1: DB - `Postgresql`

Comment: It depends on your DB engine.

Comment: If you don't give a second columns to order on, the PostgreSQL DB will return a collection with a random order (not totally true if it grabs the records from its cache, might be similar order but not reliable). Use `order('position ASC, id ASC')` to order by ID if `position` is `null` or equal to another record's `position`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

Cats:

```
id| name | position
1    5       null
2    6       null
3    7       not_null

nil     = Cat.order("id ASC").where(position: nil) = [1, 2]
not_nil = Cat.order("id ASC").where("position is not null") = [3]

not_nil + nil = [3, 1, 2]
```

This preserves order.

Answer (score 2):

According Postgres [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-order.html), if no sorting clause the records are returned according with physical position at the disk. It says nothing for sorted records with equal values on sort fields. But, it uses b-tree and, like clasic db managers, it must return on the order stored at the b-tree. You must expect that each of this change on db reorganization.

At the end, there are no warranty on the order of records with same values on sort fields.

Note: using Postgres you can make the NULL values at the first or the last (it is detailed at the referrer link).

At [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29265206/rails-records-are-not-ordered-by-id-in-heroku#29265355) related question, I'm agree with @macek.