# Rails: Records are not ordered by id in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, heroku

Im having a problem I developed my app in my local environment and everything works as espected, but after I deployed to heroku something is not working right.

I have 2 models PurchasingGroup and GroupGoal

a purchasing group has many group goals, well when I create group goals for a purchasing group I can check in the console like this

```
PurchasingGroup.last.group_goals
```

and the result is this one

```
[#<GroupGoal id: 130, created_at: "2015-03-25 17:09:08", updated_at: "2015-03-25 17:10:37", other attributes ommitted>, 
#<GroupGoal id: 131, created_at: "2015-03-25 17:09:08", updated_at: "2015-03-25 17:18:11", other attributtes ommitted]>
```

well this is right, it works like that in heroku and in my local too, when a group goal is updated the order of the records change in heroku (ONLY in heroku) so the result is like this

```
[#<GroupGoal id: 131, created_at: "2015-03-25 17:09:08", updated_at: "2015-03-25 17:10:37", other attributes ommitted>, 
#<GroupGoal id: 130, created_at: "2015-03-25 17:09:08", updated_at: "2015-03-25 17:18:11", other attributtes ommitted]>
```

so if you see now the order changed, and this breaks a lot of functionality of my application so I have to specify EVERYTIME like this

`PurchasingGroup.last.group_goals.order(:id)`

I have to specify order by :id in order to make it work in heroku. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using postgres w/Heroku, postgres sorts by the most recently updated. You'll have to override the default order in your model as in `has_many: group_goals, :order => "id DESC"`, or what have you

Comment: RAILS 4.2, just add this in a new line in your model default_scope { order(id: :asc) }

Comment: @SsouLlesS that's true, if your are using Rails 4, the newer syntax is to use a lambda scope block , as in `has_many :group_goals, -> { order(id: :asc) }`. I use Rails 3 in my app so I get away with the older syntax. Good catch!

Comment: "postgres sorts by the most recently updated" - I'm not certain this is true. I think it's "an unspecified order": http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-order.html

Comment: @jwadsack Interesting. Now you have me thinking and testing this out. In one of my Rails apps on Heroku it seems to order data that is unspecified (on a admin portal) by the most recently updated. Hmmmm looking more into this. Thanks.

Comment: We have hit this all the time in specs if you don't define and order and don't match arrays irrespective of order (e.g. rspec's `match_array` matcher), then specs may pass for one run and fail for another. With no change to the order of records added.

Answer (score 2):

If you depend on ordered results, you should **always** specify an order using `.order`

Comment: I was looking for a default way of ordering for save have to call .order everytime everywhere...